# Micromax Canvas A1 (Android One) Touch Not working

Tags: android, touch, screen, recovery

I follow [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6zq5AKH1m0) to install Android Lollipop 5.1 in my `Micromax Canvas A1` **Android ONE** device.After Installing Flash Recovery (PHILZ), i dont know what happen **Touch Screen** is not working but Lollipop 5.1 is installed, I dont know what mistake is happened. How to get out from this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Take out battery, sim and mmc.
- Press and hold power button for 2 minutes.
- Then for other 5-10 minutes, leave everything as it is.
- Now put all back
- Boot in recovery
- wipe data
- wipe cache
- wipe dalvik cache
- In mounts and storage, format /data (/data/media)
- Install stock rom zip
- reboot and check if touch is working.
- If not then waut for some time

If touch working then use your phone and if still you want that lollipop 5.1 Then follow steps below.
(Touch will work this time)

- Boot in recovery
- wipe data
- wipe cache
- wipe dalvik cache
- Go in Advance restore from external sd card
- Select boot and system
- Then restore
- wait for it to finish
- reboot